# How to create an array of function values omitting certain values

Tags: filtering, list-manipulation

I'm using `Array` to create function lists, `f[1],f[2],f[3],...,f[A]` where the values from $1$ through $A$ have unit increment. This seems an efficient way to do so for my use case: dynamically solving a large number of non-linear equations.

Sadly, some of the related non-linear equations are only defined for certain values between $1$ and $A$, and so I wish to omit the values for which the related equations are undefined. Peculiarly enough I seem to be unable to manipulate data sets created using `Array`. `DeleteCases`, something I use usually for regular "lists", requires a `pattern` that `Array` uses that I'm unaware of, so I cannot check for the right pattern to delete certain values. For example suppose my function is called `Myfunction`, then using `Fold[DeleteCases[#1,#2[[1]],#2[[2]]],Myarray,{Myfunction,ListofIndicesToDelete}]` (up to a `Transpose`, depends on the exact input) that doesn't work at all.

Suppose the following code:

```
MyLength = 50;

MyNonLinearEquation[j_] := 
 Subscript[x, j] == Sum[Subscript[x, j]*Subscript[x, k], {k, MyLength}]

MyArray = Array[MyNonLinearEquation, MyLength];
```

Suppose I wish to omit `MyNonLinearEquation[10]`, and `MyNonLinearEquation[35]`, how would I go about that? Note that we would also have to omit dependencies on these variables inside the sum.

Comment: Is it like you want to run ```MyNonLinearEquation``` skipping curtain indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$indicesToExclude = {10, 35};

arr := Array[MyNonLinearEquation, MyLength];

(*
    First method - just don't use them!
    Note you have contiguous sequence.
*)
tL1 = First@RepeatedTiming[(l1 = MyNonLinearEquation /@ DeleteCases[Range[MyLength], Alternatives @@ $indicesToExclude]);];

(*
    Second method - just don't use them!
    Say you don't contiguous sequence.
*)
tL2 = First@RepeatedTiming[(l2 = MyNonLinearEquation /@ Delete[Range[MyLength], List /@ $indicesToExclude]);];

(*
    Third method - delete at positions!
*)
tL3 = First@RepeatedTiming[(l3 = Delete[arr, List /@ $indicesToExclude]);];

(*
    Fourth method - use overload!
    While writing the response noticed @kglr, already mentioned this.
*)
tL4 = First@RepeatedTiming[(l4 = Array[MyNonLinearEquation, MyLength, 1, Delete[{##}, List /@ $indicesToExclude]&]);];

(*
    Fifth method - using table!
    Demonstrating the answer from @kglr in the benchmark.
*)
tL5 = First@RepeatedTiming[(l5 = Table[MyNonLinearEquation[i], {i, Delete[Range[MyLength], List /@ $indicesToExclude]}]);];

Dataset[<|
    "Method 1" -> <|"Time" -> tL1|>,
    "Method 2" -> <|"Time" -> tL2|>,
    "Method 3" -> <|"Time" -> tL3|>,
    "Method 4" -> <|"Time" -> tL4|>,
    "Method 5" -> <|"Time" -> tL5|>
|>]

SameQ @@ {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5} (* \[Rule] True *)
```

[image: Dataset result]

There are many more methods, you might want to tweak, but I hope this gives you the idea.

Comment: Wonderful! Went with your second method :-) Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. You can use the fourth argument of `Array` to delete unwanted positions:

```
Array[foo, 10, 1, Delete[{##}, {{3}, {7}}] &]
```

> {foo[1], foo[2], foo[4], foo[5], foo[6], foo[8], foo[9], foo[10]}

2. Define `bar` to be equal to `Nothing` for the arguments you want to skip and to `foo` for all other arguments:

```
bar = foo;
bar[3 | 7] = Nothing;
Array[bar, 10]
```

> {foo[1], foo[2], foo[4], foo[5], foo[6], foo[8], foo[9], foo[10]}

3. Alternatively, use `Table` and delete the unwanted positions in the iterator list:

```
Table[foo[i], {i, Delete[Range@10, {{3}, {7}}]}]
```

> {foo[1], foo[2], foo[4], foo[5], foo[6], foo[8], foo[9], foo[10]}

Comment: Many thanks! I only marked the other answer because the implementation was easier for my specific use case. Did upvote though:)